# How to add string in int? R.string.name+Integer.parse(myindex). not working

Tags: android, android-resources

How to add string in int?

```
R.string.name+Integer.parse(myindex).
```

not working.Link
[txtt.setText(getString(R.string.("i" + j++)));](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28132214/txtt-settextgetstringr-string-i-j)
not helpful.
others found

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Blackbelt, 
I have a String.xml 5 String.
name0, name1, name2, name3, name4.

It is necessary to automate it to be so.
R.string.name + (int)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [getIdentifier()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to retrieve the string's id, it returns  a resource identifier for the given resource name.

```
 int stringId = getResources().getIdentifier("name"+myIndex, "string", getPackageName());
 if (stringId > 0) {
   textView.setText(stringId);
 }
```

if you are looking for a String array, the syntax is slightly different:

```
int stringId = getResources().getIdentifier("name"+myIndex, "array", getPackageName());
String[] array = getResources().getStringArray( stringId );
```

Comment: `int stringId = getResources().getIdentifier("name"+indexAuthor, "string", getPackageName());
                masText = getResources().getStringArray( stringId );`

String array resource ID #0x0

Comment: no wait, are you looking for a string id or a string array id?

Comment: you are mistaken. The id of a string-array is contained in a different class. Check my update

Answer (score 0):

```
R.string.name+String.valueOf(myindex);
```

Comment: not working,

          `masText = getResources().getStringArray( R.array.name+0 `
Cannot resolve symbol 'name'