# Android at drawables dynamically

Tags: android

Hi I have some drawables that I run through via switch.

Is it possible run through these in a for statement instead?

Something like...

i=0;

String d = "tab"+i;

R.drawable.[d];

i++;

?

Thanks
Aidan

Comment: it is possible using [getIdentifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28772290/how-to-add-string-in-int-r-string-nameinteger-parsemyindex-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do something like this:

```
String d = "tab"+i;

int id = getActivity().getResources().getIdentifier(d,
                "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
```

Then set your image:

```
yourImageView.setImageResource(id);
```